# C# label.text does not change on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I know it's simple but it does not change the label.text at all. Am I missing smth or what?

```
private void btn_Main_DataZapisz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lbl_Main_Data.Text = "aaaaaaaaaa";
            lbl_Main_Data.Refresh();

        }
```

Comment: Give a bit more detail, is this code behind for ASP.NET or Windows Form?  If ASP.NET, share your aspx code where you defined lbl_Main_Data. Did you try to debug and hit the line where you set .Text value?

Comment: The text of lbl_Main_Data should be changed without performing refresh 
 put a break point on button'btn_Main_DataZapisz_Click' action to sure it's executed

Comment: It;s Windows Forms. I haven't tried debugging since I just started programming (I'm really bad}

Comment: Sounds like the event isn't subscribed.

Comment: This is not reproducible using the information you have provided.  If you create a new Windows Forms application, add a label to the form called `label1` (which is the default name), and add a button to the form, then add a `Click` event handler for the button to say `label1.Text = "aaaaaaaaaa";` it works.  You leave us guessing as to what the actual problem may be.  Such as the Click event not being set up correctly, or you misdiagnosing the problem (looking at the wrong label control or wrong form, or not running the code you think you are while diagnosing the problem.).

Comment: _I haven't tried debugging since I just started programming_ Well, that is exactly the right time ;-) -  Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got the *method* by double clicking the button in your **Form File** then it should be connected properly and the problem is something with `lbl_Main_Data`.

If you typed the method completely from scratch then it's not hooked up to the button so it doesn't know what to do when it's pressed.

To properly connect it, you single click the button in your **Form File** then look for the **Property** window. Look near the top of the **Property** window, there should be 5 different buttons under `btn_Main_DataZapisz System.Windows.Forms.Button` click the lightning bolt which is labeled "event".

Once there, find "Clicked", if there's a blank space to the right of it then the method isn't connected to the button and you can just type in the method name to connect it.

Comment: Well, setting manually click event helped. The field was the same as previous, but it fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!